# Can irrelevant external backlinks cause getting worse in a website's Alexa ranking?

Tags: seo, backlinks, ranking, bounce-rate, alexa

It's about a month that my website's (a forum for programming questions) Alexa rating is getting worse day by day, and every time that I look in Google Analytics, bounce rate is increasing and sessions and sessions duration are decreasing daily.

I should tell everything was alright until the last month. The number of users and their activity is like how it was in the past.

I checked backlinks from Google Webmaster. There are too many backlinks from pornographic websites (which are totally irrelevant from my website's field of activity). Does anyone have an idea about the problem and show me an answer?

(In my country unfortunately Alexa rating is very important for advertising agencies and they evaluate websites worth with Alexa rating.)

Answer (score 1):

No, links don't matter at all with Alexa ranking.

Alexa ranks pages based mainly on actual visits to their pages. If someone who has their toolbar installed visits a page, that counts as a hit. The more unique hits it gets, the higher they rank you.

What MAY be happening is that the amount of visits you are getting is lower than before, because of the way your site ranks in Google, Bing, and other search engines. There are SEOs that believe that getting many links from those kinds of site can get your site demoted, and others that say that they don't have any influence at all in your rankings.

Another factor to consider is that maybe other sites in your country are getting better at their own rankings, and pushing you down as a result.

A few suggestions to get you started:

- Check your site analytics, the amount of visitors you are getting,
  understand how you are getting them, your best and worst pages, etc.
- Check your site to see how it looks in mobile and desktop versions
- Fix any errors with your site pages and/or architecture
- Optimize your site for page speed
- Review security on your site
- Learn and apply SEO on your site to increase your visitors in the long run
- Run a few paid campaigns to increase visitors and thus, increase your
  Alexa rankings in the short run.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the disavow feature in Google Search Console. Read more about it here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en